# Send email to a specific recipient based on cell value

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm not a technical person and need help on using apps script.

- I have a sheet with 5 tabs (each sheet are exactly the same format of column headers)
- Column B is a dropdown of 4 points of contact. E.g. John, Anna, Peter and Michelle
- Goal: when a user selects a name from the dropdown, it will send an email to whoever was chosen.
- subject and message can be a generic template for everyone

Can someone help me with a script I can copy and paste for this?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. Have a look at this [blog post](https://www.codementor.io/@olatundegaruba/google-apps-script-automated-emails-m2m0ojq9v) to get an idea on how this could be done. It's a little bit older and the UI has changed a bit but apart from that it still works this way. Here is the documentation for the [`MailApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app) class that you will need to use. And here a link to a [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZcNmur6xiX4).

Comment: Can you share a sanitized copy of your spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the comments, StackOverflow is not a coding writing service, but I will give you a couple of keys to achieve it by yourself.

What is the main point? We need to observe the changes on the sheet, and when it coincides with  the cell that contains the email, we send the email to the one the value is in the cell.

We need to observe the changes on the sheet, how we achieve it? With an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) we can capture edits events on the Sheet, as the change of the drop-down list.

Finally we need to filter the event and only attend to the ones that are in the cell or cells that contain the drop-down.

In this example I have the cell `A1` with the drop-down of emails:

```js
const sendEmailFromSheets = (e) => {
  const range = e.range;
  const email = e.value;
  if( range.getA1Notation() === 'A1') {
    MailApp.sendEmail(email,'Message from the Sheet', 'Body')
  }
}
```

After this, we attach this function to an installable trigger with the source `From spreadsheet` and type `On change`.

With all of this, you should be able to change it to adapt it to your needs.

###### Documentation:

- [`SpreadsheetApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)
- [Event-driven Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#event-driven_triggers)